# madvise() function not working

Tags: memory, memory-management

I am trying **madvise**() to mark allocated memory as mergeable so that two applications having same pages can be merged.

While using the **madvise**() function it shows "**invalid argument**".

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/mman.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<errno.h>
#define ADDR 0xf900f000
int main()
{
        int *var1=NULL,*var2=NULL;
        size_t size=0;

        size = 1000*sizeof(int);

        var1 = (int*)malloc(size);
        var2 = (int *)malloc(size);


        int i=0;

        for(i=0;i<999;i++)
        {
                var1[i] = 1;
        }

        for(i=0;i<999;i++)
        {
                var2[i] = 1;
        }

        i = -1;

        while(i<0)
        {
                i = madvise((void *)var1, size, MADV_MERGEABLE);        //to declare mergeable

                printf("%d %p\n", i, var1);       //to print the output value
                err(1,NULL);            //to print the generated error

                i = madvise((void *)var2, size, MADV_MERGEABLE);       //to declare mergeable
                printf("%d\n", i);
        }

        return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
a.out: Invalid argument
```

Please help me.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

You can only merge whole pages. You can't merge arbitrary chunks of data.

Comment: thanks for your reply.
here I am not trying to merge the pages whereas i am trying to declare that chunk of memory as mergeable.
By declaring it mergeable, I mean that if possible then the corresponding page can be merged with some other page.

Comment: Well, then you have your answer from the system. No, it's not possible to merge arbitrarily-sized, arbitrarily-aligned chunks of data.

Comment: Align your variables and madvise addresses to page-size granularity.